# Error inflating fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm just trying to follow along with the example code on android dev to inflate a fragment in an activity. I have a more complicated project I'm working but I'm getting the same error as this simple one here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The class that extends fragment

```
package com.example.fragtest;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,false);
    }

}
```

The class that extends FragmentActivity

```
package com.example.fragtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

The xml where the fragment is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <fragment android:name="com.example.fragtest.FragOne"
       android:id="@+id/frag"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The manifest where the activity name is set

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fragtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat output

```
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragtest/com.example.fragtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.example.fragtest.FragOne.onCreateView(FragOne.java:18)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:846)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1160)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.example.fragtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  ... 11 more
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f080000, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.example.fragtest.FragOne
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
07-17 23:45:09.053: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  ... 30 more
```

Comment: "at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.NasaDailyImage.onCreate(NasaDailyImage.java:37)" What is line 37 in NasaDailyImage, inside you onCreate()?

Comment: @Sam,thanks, looks like I posted the wrong log, the correct one is now posted

Comment: Can you post how you are instantiating the fragment?

Comment: What is the file name of the portion of code you have labeled: "The xml where the fragment is"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Class that extends `FragmentActivity` you are setting the view to an XML file titled `activity_main`.  Inside of `activity_main` you have a reference to your *Fragment* code, `com.example.fragtest.FragOne`.
When that XML is loaded, the code associated with `com.example.fragtest.FragOne` is executed.  That *Fragment*'s code returns a *View* with the `R.id.activity_main`.

That XML file has a reference to the same *Fragment* code that had just instantiated it. You see the conundrum.

To resolve your issue instance a new XML file (one that is not named `activity_main`) in your *Fragment* class.  Instead of inflating `activity_main` inflate a separate XML (one that does not contain a reference to the code that called it).  Effectively `activity_main` should be the container, this new layout (for instance `fragment_layout`) will be the UI portion.

I like to think of it like this:  Despite doctrine, a *Fragment* has three portions.  The container *Activity* (this can, and in your case should, inflate a layout XML file via setContentView), the *Fragment*'s java code (this can, and in your case should, inflate a layout....something other than `activity_main`), and that *Fragment*'s associated XML file (the one that is inflated by your Fragment class, don't include a cyclical reference back to it's code).

There are, of course, loopholes to these mantras but you get the drift?

Comment: I get the drift, and thank you very much! This is just the kind of explanation I was looking for :)

Comment: easy fix, worked like a charm, thank you for taking the time to help me

Comment: Can you explain in steps. I am having the same headache problem.

Comment: Your fragment needs to inflate its own seperate layout that is defined in a seperate xml file. Try to inflate a simple linear layout with a textview

Answer (score 1):

> android:id="@+id/frag"

Your logcat indicates that your fragments id is a duplicate of another. Do you have any other XML elements with the same id? If not, have you tried cleaning your project?

```
Project->Clean...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your fragment class, it is inflating the activity_main xml file which is wrong, it should inflate your fragment's xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue . in my xml I create view instead of View

so change needed

```
<view
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="20.7dp"
          android:textColor="@color/silver_two"
         />
```

to

```
<View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="20.7dp"
          android:textColor="@color/silver_two"
         />
```