# Issue with Fragment ID, App is crashing when loading the layout for the second time

Tags: fragment-identifier

[Error inflating fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532361/error-inflating-fragment)  for this same question, App is crashing when I click on the list item for the second time which is supposed to load the same layout second time also. Can anyone please help here.